# Flutter FCM / Local notifications: how to access the full original message?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

Tried accessing the full message in onDidReceiveNotification but no candy. None of the properties in notificationResponse contain the original full message.

```
  /// Sets up Local Notifications and its Listeners
  Future<void> _localNotificationsSetup(
      BuildContext context, CashticUser currentUser) async {
    _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
        const InitializationSettings(
          android: AndroidInitializationSettings(
              '@drawable/ic_notification'),
          iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
        ), onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
            (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
      {
        log.d(notificationResponse.notificationResponseType);
        log.d(notificationResponse.actionId);
        log.d(notificationResponse.input);
        log.d(notificationResponse.id);
        log.d(notificationResponse.payload);
```

Comment: The payload could be use for that no? The onDidReceiveNotificationResponse it's for when your app is open. FirebaseMessaging.onMessage will still get triggered.

Comment: Thx for the hint, yeah, actually it can. It would have been nicer to pass the original message object in there as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

provide the payload property in the show method:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
// ...
Future<void> showFlutterNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
  if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb) {
flutterNotificationsPlugin.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification?.title,
        notification?.body,
        //...
        // message.data contains the payload
        // If your payload is in json, you might also want to encode it since flutter_local_notification accepts strings
        payload: jsonEncode(message.data),
      );
  }
 }
// this log should work now
//  log.d(notificationResponse.payload);
```